# deploying for 10.7 from 10.8 - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: xcode, macos

I am developing in Xcode 5 on Mac OS X 10.8.

To deploy an app that will run in 10.7 I assume I need the 10.7 SDK.
Is that a matter of downloading xcode 4.3 from the Mac Dev Center?

I changed the deployment setting from 10.8 to 10.7 and the app won't build:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:...

[image: error image]

So I assume it is because of this missing SDK?

Any pointers would be appreciated,

Cheers

Adam

Comment: What is the rest of the error? What symbols are undefined?

Comment: After switching the Deployment Target from 10.8 to 10.7 I get: `code`"_kUTTypeJPEG", referenced from:
      -[MyAppDelegate parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in FCPXIEAppDelegate.o`code`

Comment: So does that mean that the call to the constant/UTI "kUTTypeJPEG" can't be found in the 10.7 Frameworks (which i think aren't on my machine)?

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode go to your target > Build Phases.  In "Link Binary with Libraries" add ImageIO.framework.  Then go to product > clean and try to build again.

Comment: JuJoDi - I already had that in there and the clean removed the error - but after doing a build the errors came back. Any ideas?

Comment: In Build Settings search for "Other Linker Flags" and add "-ObjC"

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm still getting the same issue - any more ideas?

Comment: The App runs fine as a 10.8 deployment - but the change to 10.7 brings up these errors

Comment: In Build Phases > Compiled Sources make sure the .m files match the ones that are in the organizer, and if you copy any new files into your project make sure you check "Add files to target"

Comment: Everything seems in order

Comment: Can you update your question with a screen shot of the build errors so I can read them in full?

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on what might be the issue?

Comment: Worked it out - i needed to are the CoreServices Framework. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out - i needed to are the CoreServices Framework. Cool!